# understand assembled code line andl 65535 %edx

Tags: c, assemblies

I have C code and Assembly code. I do not understand line 3 and 6 of assembled code.

**C code:**

```
int arith(int x, int y, int z)
{
    int t1 = x+y;
    int t2 = z*48
    int t3= t1& 0xFFFF
    int t4 = t2 * t3
    return t4;
}
```

**Assembly code:**

```
  x at % ebp+8, y at %ebp*12, z at %ebp+16
  mol 16(%ebp), %eax
  leal (%eax, %eax, 2) % eax
  sall $4, %eax
  movl 12(%ebp) %edx
  addl 8(%ebp) %edx
  andl $65535, %edx
  imull %edx. $eax
```

on line 6, I do not understand how `65535` becomes `0xFFFF` so that we have `t3 = t1 & 0xFFFF`.

Different question:
Consider the following C functino prototype, where num_t is a data type declared using typedef:

```
 void store_prod(num_t *dest, unsigned x, num_t y)
 {*dest=x*yl}
```

Gcc generates the following assemblyu code implementing the body of the computation:

```
 dest at %ebp+8, x at ebp+12, y at %ebp+16
 mov1 12($ebp), $eax
 movl 20($ebp), $ecx
 imull $eax, $ecx
 mull 16(%ebp)
 leal (%ecx,%edx), %edx
 movl 8(%ebp), %ecx
 movl %eax, (%ecx)
 movl %edx, 4(%ecx)
```

line movl 20(%ebp), %ecx there is value in 20(%ebp), how is it grabbing y_t?
line leal (%ecx, %edx), %edx; there is nothing in edx? so what is being added to %ecx to be stored in %edx?

Comment: They are the same number, just different representations. 0xFFFF is the hexadecimal representation of decimal 65535.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=0xFFFF

Comment: In some languages like delphi, the $ indicates what follows is a hex value but In GAS syntax (http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/GAS_Syntax) it only means it's a literal value.

Comment: The result of mull produces a 64bit result that ends up in edx and eax.  http://www.fermimn.gov.it/linux/quarta/x86/mul.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We want to calculate

t2=z*48

So to do that we first do z=z*3 then shift z left by 4(multiply by 16 ==left shift by 4)

line 3 calculates

z=z*3 (z+2z)

And line 4 does left shift by 4.

The compiler often generates combination of add and shift to perform multiplication as multiplication is more costly
As for line 6 65535 is decimal for 0xFFFF.